# Proving linear independence of intersecting planes.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If two planes intersect at a line passing through the origin and we are given two sets of vectors $\{\textbf{d}, \textbf{v}_i\}$ where $\textbf{d}$ is the direction vector of the line and the sets are the bases for the two planes, how do I show that the sum of the two planes forms $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each plane is a 2-dimensional vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. There exists a vector $v$ in the second plane $P_2$, which doesn't belong to the first plane $P_1$, since we know they intersect only at a line. Thus, the subspace $P_1 + \operatorname{span} v$ is 3-dimensional. Since the whole vector vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$ is also 3-dimensional, it must be the case that $P_1 + \operatorname{span} v = \mathbb{R}^3$. ∎

Answer (score 0):

The only way $\text{span}\{v_i\}$ is 2-dimensional is for the basis vectors of one plane to be both linearly dependent to the basis of the first plane -- which makes the two plane the same plane.

Your question is thus trivially true.

P.S. Next time, please show what you have done. Especially so since the question seems to be asking for granularity instead of general ideas.